# How to create an executable for Ruby console application

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a simple console app, but instead of distributing it as a script (somefile.rb), I want it as a binary file, like an executable.

Any idea?

Comment: You're looking to turn your ruby program into a binary. Checkout something like this https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby

Comment: When you say ordinary app what do you mean exactly? Some app that you double-click and runs or a command line application?

Comment: On most operating systems, scripts *are* ordinary apps. There is no difference. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, in that case, I wanted to distribute as a binary, not as a script.

Comment: @CarlosFelicianoBarba exactly.

Comment: @Adam worked like a charm, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Embedded Ruby (or better mruby) into C or C++

Simple one file with script as text.

Here is example for mruby [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/wiki/Hello-World).